# Не добавляются данные в таблицу БД

Tags: php, mysql

Требуется внести данные через php скрипт в таблицу БД. Для соединения с БД используется файл  connect.php , для добавления данных add.php  и страница, в которой можно будет посмотреть таблицу с данными - index.php. На сервере создана БД с именем database и таблица в ней с именем templog. 
 Ошибок нет, но и при этом данные не добавляются.

**connect.php**

```
<?php

function Connection(){
    $server="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="123456";
    $db="database";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);

    if (!$connection) {
        die('MySQL ERROR: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    mysqli_select_db($connection,$db ) or die( 'MySQL ERROR: '. mysqli_error() );

    return $connection;
}?>
```

**add.php**

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$link=Connection();

$temp1=$_POST['temp1'];
$hum1=$_POST['hum1'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `templog` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
    VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$hum1."')"; 

mysqli_query($link,$query);
mysqli_close($link);
header("Location: index.php");?>
```

**index.php**

```
  <?php

    include("connect.php");     

    $link=Connection();

    $result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `templog` ORDER BY `timeStamp` DESC");
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sensor Data</title>
   </head>
<body>
   <h1>Temperature / moisture sensor readings</h1>

   <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Temperature&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Moisture&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

      <?php 
          if($result!==FALSE){
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%s </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
                   $row["timeStamp"], $row["temperature"], $row["humidity"]);
             }
             mysqli_free_result($result);
             mysqli_close($link);
          }
      ?>

   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: для начала неплохо бы было посмотреть результат работы mysqli_query, глядишь и ошибки появятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После

```
mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

Делайте:

```
var_dump(mysqli_error($link));
```

Может у вас таблица не создана. Или в другой базе данных находится. 
Ваш код проверил, он хоть и страшноват, но работает и index.php и add.php.

Убедитесь, что приходят $_POST параметры в **add.php**.

Comment: Таблица создана  находится в нужно базе данных. Вот результат



`Notice: Undefined index: temp1 in D:\Server\htdocs\www\add.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: hum1 in D:\Server\htdocs\www\add.php on line 7

string(61) "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'temperature' at row 1"`

Comment: Вот видите. **1)** В `$_POST` не приходит temp1 и hum1. Может, вам из `$_GET`-параметра нужно брать? **2)** В поле temperature пытается вставиться пустая строка (из-за пункта 1), а поле у вас объявлено как int - т.е. числовое. В общем, вам нужно смотреть почему не приходят параметры в add.php.

Comment: точно, исправил POST на GET и данные добавились. Спасибо) Странно, что в статье используется POST и все работает. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @Stanislav если ответ вас устраивает, можете пометить его галочкой)